# Recover Deleted Zip file from macOS High Sierra

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, data-recovery, file-recovery

Today I faced a low memory warning on my Macbook Pro 2015.

I opened Storage Management application and started deleting unnecessary files and I accidentally removed a zip file.

I instantly opened the Trash to check whether the file was placed there or not. But the file wasn't there.

Is there any possibility to recover such files which have been removed via the Storage Management application and not manually deleted by <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Storage Management application will delete files without moving them to the trash.

You cannot restore them.

Your Mac has an SSD which will instantly execute the TRIM command. So, your Mac has already overwritten the file with something else. Data Recovery software also won't help. If you have a backup, try recovering the zip file from it.